# Adding popover to a button in Angular-based project

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I am new to Angular and I started creating a simple page, that contains data of some legal case. I have imported this library (not sure about the nomenclature) called Angular Material, because it offered some nice icons and I needed them to be displayed next to my plaintiff and second party names, so the user can have a swift peek their details.

What I want to achieve is something like this:
[design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGcwY.png)

But instead, when I add these usual tooltip attributes from official Bootstrap page:

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"
```

I get a plain, white, non-styled tooltip at the right bottom corner of my icon (instead of black one above the element).

The question is: what can I do to get this specific effect presented by Bootstrap documentation?
Here is my component code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4">Case: {{ caseTitle }}</h1>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Plaintiff: {{ clientName }} <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
        info
        </i></h3>
    <hr>
    <h5>Role: {{ clientRole }}</h5>
    <hr>
    <h5>Second party: {{ secondParty }}<i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
        info
        </i></h5>
</div>
```

And here's my component .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-case-view',
  templateUrl: './case-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./case-view.component.scss']
})
export class CaseViewComponent implements OnInit {

  caseTitle:string = "Sum cays";
  clientName:string = "Cuss Tomer";
  clientRole:string = "plain tiff";
  secondParty:string = "Dnoces Ytrap";  

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  } 

}
```

I have no idea if there's something more I should place here or in some other file, but let me also present my index.html and app.module.ts files:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LFMSfront</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Literata&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CaseViewComponent } from './case-view/case-view.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CaseViewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Try to remove class -jumbotron, you need to inspect you code, First try one tool tip if its working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use The Angular Material Tooltip instead. Here is a working example:

**HTML file**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4">Case: {{ caseTitle }}</h1>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Plaintiff: {{ clientName }} <i class="material-icons"  matTooltip="Tooltip information" [matTooltipPosition]="'after'">
        info
        </i></h3>
    <hr>
    <h5>Role: {{ clientRole }}</h5>
    <hr>
    <h5>Second party: {{ secondParty }}<i class="material-icons" matTooltip="Tooltip information" [matTooltipPosition]="'after'">
        info
        </i></h5>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts file**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CaseViewComponent } from './case-view/case-view.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CaseViewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTooltipModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

your component.ts and index.html files remain the same.

You can check [this link](https://v6.material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview) in which you will find more examples about how you  can integrate it in your application and customize it if needed.

Comment: Thank you, it works! The tooltip is now as per my design.